# The forgetful functor $U:\mathbf{B}G\to\mathbf{Sets}$ need not preserve infinite limits.

Tags: category-theory, topological-groups, limits-colimits, topos-theory, forgetful-functors

This is **Exercise I.7** of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic [. . .]"*.

Here $\mathbf{B}G$ is the category of all continuous $G$-sets, where $G$ is a topological group.

### The Question:

> Show that the forgetful functor $U:\mathbf{B}G\to\mathbf{Sets}$ need not preserve infinite limits.

### Thoughts:

I have considered the contrapositive: that if some $U':\mathbf{B}G\to\mathbf{Sets}$ preserves infinite limits, then it is not a forgetful functor. I don't think this is the best way to go about it.

---

Next, similarly, I thought that I could attempt a proof by contradiction, by assuming $U$ always preserves infinite limits, but this time working with the forgetful functor and aiming for a contradiction in $\mathbf{Sets}$.

To this end, I have some category $\mathbf{I}$ to function as the infinite diagram category that acts on both $\mathbf{B}G$ and $\mathbf{Sets}$. So consider

$$\begin{align}
U_\mathbf{I}: (\mathbf{B}G)^\mathbf{I} & \longrightarrow\mathbf{Sets}^\mathbf{I}\\
((X, \sigma)\stackrel{f}{\to}(Y, \tau))^\mathbf{I} & \stackrel{?}{\mapsto} (X\stackrel{f}{\to} Y)^\mathbf{I}.
\end{align}$$

Does the map $U_\mathbf{I}$ have to satisfy some universal property or something with respect to $\mathbf{I}$? I'm quite lost here.

I'm not sure how to work with $((X, \sigma)\stackrel{f}{\to}(Y, \tau))^\mathbf{I}$ and $(X\stackrel{f}{\to} Y)^\mathbf{I}$ either, whatever they are.

---

I think what I have so far might even be nonsense.

---

Please help :)

Comment: Do you know how to compute any limit explicitly in $\mathbb{B}G$? Have you tried to compute a product of $2$ continuous $G$-sets?

Comment: No and yes, respectively, @ThibautBenjamin. I have a rough idea how to do the former though.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the obvious question, but you haven't mentionned this in your potential approaches. I would try to compute the product of 2 continuous $G$-sets in the hope that it is not supported by the product of the $2$ underlying sets

Comment: @ThibautBenjamin it seems clear from the problem statement that an infinite product will be needed.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Indeed, I read "finite limits" instead of "infinite limits"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to show that $G$ generally does not act continuously and consistent with the actions on $A_i$ on an infinite product in $\mathbf{Set}$ of continuous $G$-sets $A_i$. Hint: under the action induced from the $A_i$, what is the stabilizer of $(a_i)_{i\in I}$? What kind of intersections of open subgroups remain open?

Comment: Does this means then that the forgetful functor is not right adjoint to a "free continous G-set" functor ?

Comment: @jeanmfischer That's right. In fact continuous $G$-sets are *co*reflective in the category of sets with an action of the discrete group $G^\delta$ on the underlying set of $G$. Thus there exists a *co*-free continuous $G$-set on a set, by composing with the *right* adjoint to the forgetful functor $G^\delta\to\mathbf{Set}$, but not in general a free one.